# Date Manipulation in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried different functions to convert `Datepart` for year, month and day to a date but I am getting errors.

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(datetime, CHAR(YEAR(GETDATE()) + CHAR(DATEPART(MM, '02')) + CHAR(DATEPART(DD, '28')));
```

When running this code, I get an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

In case I remove those single quotes on 02 and 28 then SQL will return null.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is obviously SQL Server so I tagged it as such.

Answer (score 2):

If 2012+ you could also try DateFromParts()

```
Select DateFromParts(2016,2,28)
```

Returns

```
2016-02-28
```

Comment: Thanks john: I use this, SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(DATENAME(YEAR,GETDATE()),02,28); I combined both answers then the result was what I was expecting.

Comment: @JoelMayerMukanya  Just to shorten it a bit   Select DateFromParts(Year(GetDate()),2,28)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, DATENAME(YEAR, GETDATE()) + '-02-28')
```

You can't extract a day or month from a string such as '02'.  But there is no need to do that anyway.

Comment: Still throwing an exception: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. Thank u for ur remark, I will keep it in mind

Comment: @JoelMayerMukanya . . . What if you do `CONVERT(datetime, '2016-02-18')`?  This should be equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the documentation on [`DATEPART`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx), the second parameter should be a date parameter:

> Returns an integer that represents the specified datepart of the specified **date**.

In your SQL statement you are misusing this function twice... following are invalid because the second parameter cannot be converted to a date type:

- `DATEPART(MM,'02')`
- `DATEPART(DD,'28')`

---

You can construct a date from its parts using the [`DATEFROMPARTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx) function in SQL Server 2012 and later versions:

> Returns a date value for the specified year, month, and day.

Or if you need the time parts filled in as well, [`DATETIMEFROMPARTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213233.aspx)

> Returns a datetime value for the specified date and time.

---

In versions prior to SQL Server 2012, this can be done like this:

```
DATEADD(MM, (@year - 1900) * 12 + @month - 1 , @day - 1);
```